# How to write two parasmeters in Spring MyBatis Mapper?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm currently implements Comments on comments.

When a member views a given post, they should be able to see comments on comments and comments.

To satisfy the above conditions, you need the index value of the post and the index value of the comment. That is, two parameter values ​​are required.

So I wrote the following logic.

boardDaoMapper.xml

```
<select id="selectCommentOfComment" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultType="java.util.HashMap">
    select * from board_comment_of_comment where board_idx = #{board_idx} and board_comm_idx = #{board_comm_idx}
</select>
```

And the BoardDao code:

```
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> selectCommentOfComment(int board_idx, int board_comm_idx);
```

And the BoardService:

```
@Override
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getBoardCommentOfComment(int board_idx, int board_comm_idx) 
{
    System.out.println("ServieImple getBoardCommentOfComment Function Call >> " + board_idx + " / " + board_comm_idx);
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> c_of_c_list = boardDao.selectCommentOfComment(board_idx, board_comm_idx);
    return c_of_c_list;
}
```

And BoardController code:

```
@RequestMapping("viewPage.do")
public String viewPage(HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,Model model, 
        @RequestParam(value="board_idx", defaultValue="1") int board_idx) throws IOException,IllegalStateException
{
    checkLogin(request, response, session);


    // 해당 게시물에 대한 댓글들의 idx값 조회 (board_comm_idx)
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> commentList= bService.getBoardForComment(boardData.getBoard_idx());

    System.out.println("Board_idx Value was : " + board_idx);

    // 해당 게시물에 대한 댓글들의 개수만큼 for문을 돌고..
    for(int i = 0; i < commentList.size(); i++)
    {
        // board_comm_idx 값을 변수에 저장
        int board_comm_idx= (Integer) commentList.get(i).get("board_comm_idx");
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCommentOfComentList =  
                    bService.getBoardCommentOfComment(board_idx, board_comm_idx);
        System.out.println("GetCommentOfCommentList : " + getCommentOfComentList);
        model.addAttribute("cocList", getCommentOfComentList);
    }

    return "viewPage";
}
```

Values ​​are good for two parameters.(at BoardService) Like that..

```
ServieImple getBoardCommentOfComment Function Call >> 2 / 3
```

However, this does not perform well and causes an error.

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'board_idx' not found. Available parameters are [0, 1, param1, param2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$ParamMap.get(MapperMethod.java:165)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.MapWrapper.get(MapWrapper.java:44)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.getValue(MetaObject.java:116)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.createCacheKey(BaseExecutor.java:186)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.createCacheKey(CachingExecutor.java:129)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:108)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:358)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:198)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:119)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.selectCommentOfComment(Unknown Source)
    at service.BoardServiceImple.getBoardCommentOfComment(BoardServiceImple.java:367)
    at controller.BoardController.viewPage(BoardController.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
```

I think Mapper has a problem.

Why is this happening and how should I fix it?

Your comments are valuable. Please tell me your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

***The problem with the current approach***

You currently your mapping set up in a way that doesn't accept your parameters into the DAO layer `parameterType="java.util.HashMap"`

This being the case, iBatis is expecting a HashMap to be passed.

There are multiple ways that you can go about fixing your code.

**1.) Using Named Parameters (Depending on your version) > 3**

`public List<HashMap<String, Object>> selectCommentOfComment(@Param("board_idx") int board_idx, @Param("board_comm_idx") int board_comm_idx);`

And remove the parameter type from your mapping xml.

**2.) Pass in the expected object**

You can fix your DAO method signature to reflect your mapping. And make the corresponding changes in the service.

*DAO:*

`public List<HashMap<String, Object>> selectCommentOfComment(HashMap<String, Object> parameter);`

*SERVICE:*

```
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getBoardCommentOfComment(int board_idx, int board_comm_idx) 
{
   HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   parameters.put("board_idx", board_idx);
   parameters.put("board_comm_idx", board_comm_idx");
   List<HashMap<String, Object>> c_of_c_list = boardDao.selectCommentOfComment(board_idx, board_comm_idx);
   return c_of_c_list;
}
```

You can draw additional inspiration from their documentation.
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html

Comment: I solved it but encountered another problem. 
Can you chat with me 1:1?

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: If you add a comment to a comment and you log in with a different name and comment on the comment, they will be displayed well, but when you create a new comment, the comment is not displayed in the comment that was created. However, all values ​​are stored in the log.

Comment: I will explain by photograph.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pi1yQ , https://imgur.com/a/dwT7R , https://imgur.com/a/J8vyz
In the first picture, If you log in with a different ID and comment on the comment, the list will be displayed well.But if you look at the second picture, When you create a new comment, the comment list disappears from the existing comment. If you look at the third picture, you want to see more value in this list, but it can not be displayed.

Comment: I suspect EL is a problem. Do you think so?